# Assign output of command to environment variable different from original output (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, process, environment-variables, lines

I have encountered a problem with a script I have originally designed.

I am trying to get the number of lines a command displays and if the number is bigger than a value, something should happen.

My problem is that originally this worked fine, now it doesn't.

In my script I am using the following command

```
NO_LINES=$(ps -ef | grep "sh monitor.sh" | wc -l)
echo $NO_LINES
```

`echo $NO_LINES` prints `0` even though it should print `1`, the line for the grep command.

If I execute the command separately (not assigning the result to an environment variable) like this

```
ps -ef | grep "sh monitor.sh" | wc -l
```

This will print out `1` which is the correct result.

Why is it that by assigning the result to the variable, the value is lower with 1 than the original result?

The bash version of the machine is 4.3.46(1)-release.

Thanks

Comment: Couple of things here 1) You do not have an environment variable set 2) How are you running the script `sh monitor.sh` in fore ground or background?

Comment: `sh monitor.sh` is the name of the process I am looking for, which either runs in background, or doesn't at all. The first two lines are from another script that tries to start the monitor.sh script. And yes my bad.. assigning this to a variable

Comment: Why can't you use `pgrep` directly for checking if process by the name `sh monitor.sh` exists or not? if that is your requirement! Is your intention just to see if the process is available? @Ancuta

Comment: Have you tried adding `ps -ef` inside your script ? Does it show `sh monitor.sh` in its output ?

Comment: @inian yes I know there are alternatives to this problem, to check if a process is running and get its PID, but I have originally designed it like this and it worked. I am curious as to why when assigning the result to NO_LINES it is lower with one than the actual result (this always happens).

Comment: @Ancuta: I _doubt_ if it is really always one lesser that way, I think no matter what the variable is outputting a result as `0`

Comment: @Aserre if the script is running, yes the output includes `sh monitor.sh`. But that is not my problem. My problem is the difference in values and why is it there.

Comment: @Inian: I beg to differ. If the `sh monitor.sh` process is running the `ps -ef | grep "sh monitor.sh" | wc -l` displays `2` and the `echo $NO_LINES` displays `1`. If the `sh monitor.sh` process is not running then the outputs are `1` for the `ps -ef | grep "sh monitor.sh" } wc -l` command and `0` for the `echo $NO_LINES` command

Comment: @Inian also I want to see if the process is running and if so get its PID and kill it.

Comment: @Ancuta: Don't tell me you _actually think_ the `wc -l` is returning the count of lines in the `monitor.sh` script. It _DOES NOT_, the count you are seeing is output of lines of output from `ps -ef | grep "sh monitor.sh"` run from the command line

Comment: @Inian I never said that. The `monitor.sh` script has hundreds of lines of code. I _KNOW_ `wc -l` returns the number of lines the command displays, and i know my command is `ps -ef | grep "sh monitor.sh"` and this should return either one line or two lines, depending if the `sh monitor.sh` process is running.

Comment: @Ancuta: Fair enough! Can you try excluding the `grep` process as `ps -ef | grep "sh monitor.sh" | grep -v grep|  wc -l` both in command line and from the variable and try once?

Comment: @Inian If i add the `grep -v grep` to my command both results are `0` if the process is not running and `1` if the process is running.

Comment: @Ancuta: So that is the problem we are seeing. The `grep` command has actually included itself as a running process when you ran the `ps`, so `grep -v grep` excluded that from the search result.

Comment: @Inian yes I know that. But why are there two different results if it is assigned to a variable compared to just executing the command.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your problem, but the shell script seems to work fine. So this leaves me to wonder: When running the shell script, are you absolutely sure that `monitor.sh` is running? As @Aserre mentioned: have you tried re-defining your BASH-variable as `NO_LINES=$(ps -ef)` and checked the output of `echo $NO_LINES` in that case? Is `monitor.sh` in the output?

Comment: @SB87 yes I have tried that and the script seems to run, but if the `monitor.sh` script isn't running, the `ps -ef | grep "sh monitor.sh" | wc -l` should display `1`, the line for the `grep "sh monitor.sh"` process. I have tested this on a different system and, if the script is running the `$NO_LINES` is `2`, otherwise `$NO_LINES` is `1`. But on this specific system, the `$NO_LINES` for when the script is running is `1`, and if the script is not running the variable is `0`, omitting the line for the `grep` process. If i just check `ps -ef | grep "sh monitor.sh"` the lines displayed are correct